# How to get this object

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to do a image gallery, but can't find the logic here, I did many test and searches but I'm stuck.

I'm try to get the next image using current image id

the button event is in a modal of bootstrap

```js
$("#btn").click(function(ev){

    //i get this id from somewhere, this part is done
    current_img_id = "img_1";
    
    //i try to get the next image using current image id
    img_next = $("#collection > div > #" + current_img_id).closest(".img_iterate").next();
  
  //then i will pass the object some where
  somewhere(img_next);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="collection">

  <div class="style">
    <a id="img_1" class="img_iterate">
      <img src="some_1.jpg">
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="style">
    <a id="img_2" class="img_iterate">
      <img src="some_2.jpg">
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="style">
    <a id="img_3" class="img_iterate">
      <img src="some_3.jpg">
    </a>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: i'm try to get the next image using current image id

Comment: You are missing one level. Next is still inside the div. When in doubt debug your logic using `console.log`

Comment: u mean .closest("div > a.img_iterate") ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i added an ID to the second div and then search for the image inside.